# Why is the ListView with an ImageList very slow? (re: 1000+ thumbnails)

Tags: winforms, listview, thumbnails, imagelist

I'm trying to use a ListView component to show around 1,000 image thumbnails and I'm having some performance problems.

First I create an ImageList containing my 1,000 images.  This is lightning fast and takes under a second.

However, once I assign the ImageList to my ListView, it takes around 10+ seconds.

Example:

```
ImageList _imgList = GetMyImageList();  // takes under 1 second
ListView _lstView = new ListView();
lstView.LargeImageList = _imgList; // takes 10+ seconds
```

Is there anything I can do to increase performance?  My ImageList contains images that are already resized into thumbnail size (197x256 pixels) so that's not the problem... (and creating my ImageList only takes 1 second at the most).

Comment: See my answer below and try the code on your machine and let me know if there is a difference in loading times.

Answer (score 0):

Does the data in your list view change frequently? Do you load new image lists frequently?

I tried your scenario and got a few seconds of loading time (since I'm generating random images) but very fast refresh times when changing list view `[View]` modes as well as scrolling.

Here is the sample code. Try it out and let me know how it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication10
{
    public partial class FormListView:
        System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public FormListView ()
        {
            string [] names = null;

            this.InitializeComponent();

            names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(View));
            for (int i=0; i < names.Length; i++)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add(names [i]);

                if (names [i] == this.ListView.View.ToString())
                    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ListView.View = (View) Enum.Parse(typeof(View), this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            this.ListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        }

        private void ButtonLoadImages_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Image image;
            Stopwatch watch;

            this.Enabled = false;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            this.ListView.SmallImageList = null;
            this.ListView.LargeImageList = null;
            this.ListView.StateImageList = null;

            while (this.ImageList.Images.Count > 0)
            {
                this.ImageList.Images [0].Dispose();
                this.ImageList.Images.RemoveAt(0);
            }

            this.ImageList.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(256, 256);

            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                image = new Bitmap(this.ImageList.ImageSize.Width, this.ImageList.ImageSize.Height);
                using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                {
                    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                    graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 10, 10, this.ImageList.ImageSize.Width - 20, this.ImageList.ImageSize.Height - 20);
                    graphics.DrawString(i.ToString(), this.Font, Brushes.Blue, 20, 20);
                }
                this.ImageList.Images.Add(image);
            }
            watch.Stop();

            this.ListView.SmallImageList = this.ImageList;
            this.ListView.LargeImageList = this.ImageList;
            this.ListView.StateImageList = this.ImageList;

            this.Text = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            this.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void ButtonLoadItems_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch watch;
            ListViewItem item;

            this.Enabled = false;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            this.ListView.Items.Clear();
            this.ListView.Columns.Clear();
            this.ListView.Columns.Add("Id", "Id");
            this.ListView.Columns.Add("Name", "Name");

            this.ListView.SmallImageList = null;
            this.ListView.LargeImageList = null;
            this.ListView.StateImageList = null;

            this.ListView.BeginUpdate();
            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                item = new ListViewItem();

                item.ImageIndex = i;
                item.Text = i.ToString();
                item.SubItems.Add("qwerty");

                this.ListView.Items.Add(item);
            }
            this.ListView.EndUpdate();

            this.ListView.SmallImageList = this.ImageList;
            this.ListView.LargeImageList = this.ImageList;
            this.ListView.StateImageList = this.ImageList;

            this.ListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);

            watch.Stop();

            this.Text = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString();

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            this.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```